# Build failed Liferay 6.2 application

Tags: liferay-6.2

I am trying to configure an existing liferay 6.2 application in my eclipse IDE but I am unable to build the application. The problem seems to be in ivy.xml file. The dependencies present there are not getting auto downloaded.
Following is the code present in ivy.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <ivy-module version="2.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
   <info module="portlet_primefaces_tmpl" organisation="com.liferay" />

    <dependencies defaultconf="default">
        <dependency name="el-api" org="javax.el" rev="2.2" />
        <dependency name="jboss-el" org="org.jboss.el" rev="2.0.1.GA" />
        <dependency name="jsf-api" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.1.21" />
        <dependency name="jsf-impl" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.1.21" />
        <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-api" org="com.liferay.faces"    rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
        <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-impl" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
        <dependency name="liferay-faces-portal" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
        <dependency name="liferay-faces-util" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
        <dependency name="primefaces" org="org.primefaces" rev="3.5" />
    </dependencies>
    </ivy-module>
```

The error while building the application :

> BUILD FAILED
>   E:\Liferay_Project_Edistrict\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\build-common-ivy.xml:81: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a question similar to this and while your post is also short on details you might be experiencing a common issue in some 6.2 minor releases.  Find your build.USERNAME.properties file and add the following lines, then try to build again

```
ivy.version = 2.3.0 
ivy.jar.url = http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.version}/ivy-${ivy.version}.jar
```